# Spring boot : Field names from properties file, and field values at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I've a scenario to solve, where I need to maintain some key-value pairs in the code. The key names are to be read from properties file. Which I'm going to do like this in spring boot.

```
    @Data
    @ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "project.keysList" )
    public class KeyNames {
    private String key1Name;
    private String key2Name;
    ...
    }
```

I'll get the corresponding values during the run-time. How can I store the values elegantly ? These are the options I'm considering.

1. Define one more model object called `KeyValues` and store them.
2. Define a hashmap called `KeyValues` and store the `keyNames` and corresponding values.

Is there a better way other than these two, where I don't need to define a new object for storing the values, which I get during the run time.?

Appreciate any help in this..
Pls ask for clarifications in case my qn is not too clear.

Answer (score 0):

Define your key and value in resources folder of application.properties file and define `@Value` annotation in the above your `Configuration class` of field name.

For example:

`application.properties` file

```
key1.name=valuename
key2.name=valuename
```

============================

```
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "project.keysList" )
public class KeyNames {

@Value("${key1.name}")
private String key1Name;

@Value("${key2.name}")
private String key2Name;
}
```

Comment: Thnx fr the answer. The values, I don't have before run time.. That's the issue.
I've all the keynames that I can read from properties file. The corresponding values of these keynames are obtained during runtime. I'm just figuring out the best way to store the values corresponding to these keynames..

Answer (score 0):

@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")

public class CustomProperties {

```
private Long id;

private String name;

private String phone;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Thnx fr the answer. The values, I don't have before run time.. That's the issue. I've all the keynames that I can read from properties file. The corresponding values of these keynames are obtained during runtime. I'm just figuring out the best way to store the values corresponding to these keynames..

Comment: Create a Bean related Mysql or Redis. Use Spring manage it. You can change Bean's properties in the dataBase without  restart App